# strange issue while using FOR loop and here document inside a script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

In the below script the output file is missing the header record.
Some data from the PTF_LIST is also missing in the output
The same script if run with one value in the PTF_LIST
e.g PTF_LIST="LIST1" produces the header record and the data for the list in the output

The script when run with multiple values for PTT_LIST e.g PTF_LIST="LIST1 LIST2 LIST3" does not produce the desired output.
The header record is missing and data for the some list values randomly does not appear in the output file.

Only a single instance of the script is run at a time.

```
#!/bin/ksh

OUTPUT_FILE=report_output.csv

WRKFILE=temp_ouput.tmp


# Header record.
print "column1, column2, column3" > ${OUTPUT_FILE}

PTF_LIST="LIST1 LIST2 LIST3 LIST4 LIST5 LIST6 LIST7" 

for PTF_NO in $PTF_LIST
do

/usr/bin/isql -b -s',' -U$USER -P$USERPWD <<-EOT | sed -e 's/ *,/,/g' >${WRKFILE} 2>&1

use aaamaindb
go
set nocount on
set dateformat ymd
go

exec some_function @port_object='${PTF_NO}'
go  
EOT

awk -F',' '{ if ( $5 == "YES" ) { print $1","$2","$3","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13}}'  < ${WRKFILE} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE}

done #End of for loop
```

thanks for your comments and answers.

Comment: Good that you have shown your code in your question. It is always recommended to add your samples of Input and expected output for better understanding of question, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: I don't see why the header record wouldn't show up, regardless of what is assigned to `PTF_LIST` *unless* there are some unwanted control characters being copied from `${WKRFILE}` to `${OUTPUT_FILE}`; have you reviewed the contents of (each) `${WRKFILE}` (eg, `od -c ${WRKFILE}`) for any unwanted control characters?

Comment: Do you see the data with `tr -d '\r' report_output.csv` ?